# onSaveInstanceState doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity

when screen rotates ...  Toast print nothing !

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    String a  = savedInstanceState.getString("hello");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    String a = "WTF";
    outState.putString("hello",a);
}
```

}

I declared everything nicely,, where is the bummer in this simple code !?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you've fallen into a really common trap many devs have since the Android OS team overloaded the `onSaveInstanceState()` method.

You are overriding the **wrong method**. The one you want is:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    String a = "WTF";
    outState.putString("hello",a);
}
```

Personally, I think Craig Mautner should be forced to donate money every time an Android developer makes this mistake - [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a002604af0c9b1204556610537b85685d7055996%5E%21)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem
Try to change to this

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    String a = "WTF";
    outState.putString("hello",a);
}
```